# Where can I find the list of Docker format template variables?

Tags: docker

I can't find the Docker documentation that outlines the list of template variables that can be used with the --format flag.

e.g. I know this works: `docker ps --format {{.Name}}` and returns a list of the running containers by name. I have searched through the docs and cannot find a reference to the variables that are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do a `docker inspect container_id` and you have a nearly full list.

Keep in mind that there is a hierarchy, so you can do

`docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Running }}' 21d`

that can show

`true`

or

`docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' 21d`

that can show

`2015-09-03T08:08:42.204866274Z`

Something like

`docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Env }}' 21d`

may return a list

See also the reference post on that subject

http://container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic/

Comment: I really wish there was a docs page or something for this, but your answer will suffice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The valid placeholders for `--format` are available at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting

For completeness, this is what it says right now for v1.13:

- `.ID`:    Container ID
- `.Image`: Image ID
- `.Command`: Quoted command
- `.CreatedAt`: Time when the container was created.
- `.RunningFor`: Elapsed time since the container was started.
- `.Ports`: Exposed ports.
- `.Status`: Container status.
- `.Size`: Container disk size.
- `.Names`: Container names.
- `.Labels`: All labels assigned to the container.
- `.Label`: Value of a specific label for this container. For example `"com.docker.swarm.cpu"`
- `.Mounts`: Names of the volumes mounted in this container.
- `.Networks`: Names of the networks attached to this container.

Comment: Please note this is the **subset** of template variables that applies to the `docker ps` (view running containers) command. There are numerous others available for use with `docker inspect`, but at this time there isn't similar documentation for formatting that command on the Docker site. The command `docker inspect <sha_image_id>` will output the metadata for a particular image which shows which placeholders are available, at least for that particular image.

Comment: Personally, I use `docker ps --format '{{json .}}'` to convert all fields in scope (the `.`) to JSON as a "quick reference" for what fields are defined. Bonus points for piping it through a tool like jq or fx to make it more human friendly.